# Is it possible to read/write another process' memory using the new Apple Endpoint Security Framework?

Tags: macos, kernel-extension, macos-system-extension

With kexts we could to `vm_read/vm_write`, is there a similar way for Endpoint Security?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot generally obtain other processes' task ports in an Endpoint Security system extension, so while the API exists (`mach_vm_read()` etc.) you can typically only obtain the task port for child processes, or if a process sends its own task port to your process via a Mach message.